# An error occurred while searching for additional drivers. I was just looking for additional drivers and this msg displayed. How to solve this error

Tags: drivers

[image]

I have rebooted the system done *sudo apt update* and *sudo apt upgrade* and then rebooted again but this error message does not go away. Actually I wanted to intall WiFi driver and I have succeeded in that but this error message remains. If someone knows how to resolve this, I request them to post a method. Many thanks!! (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

The output of sudo apt update is:

```
   [sudo] password for chess: 
Get:1 https://deb.opera.com/opera-developer stable InRelease [2,591 B]
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                          
Hit:3 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                               
Hit:4 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease                                                   
Hit:5 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic InRelease                                              
Get:6 https://deb.opera.com/opera-developer stable/non-free amd64 Packages [1,796 B]                                     
Hit:7 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                       
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                             
Hit:9 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                      
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                                               
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu focal InRelease                                               
Hit:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                               
Hit:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease                                                  
Hit:14 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                    
Hit:15 http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease                                                                      
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/foliate/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                 
Hit:17 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                        
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                          
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelebek333/kablosuz/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease                                              
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                           
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                     
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                      
Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                    
Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                          
Hit:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xuzhen666/gnome-mpv/ubuntu focal InRelease                                               
Fetched 114 kB in 11s (10.2 kB/s)                                                                                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: Is it Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Yes thanks. :) I am updating the question now.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes. Connected to internet.

Comment: Please add output of `sudo apt update` to your question.

Comment: Added now. There is some error when sudo apt update to. It has taken me a lot of time to update the WIFi driver. Tried so many things and finally succeeded but this error remains. I am a new Ubuntu user. Previously I used Windows.

Comment: Hi! I did sudo update again and now no errors in it. But the additional driver error is still there. Updating my question again with new sudo apt update output.

Comment: What driver you want to install? Maybe there is some problem with mirrors. You can always isntall drivers manually if you need any.

Comment: No I have already installed the driver for WiFi. Now I do not want to install any other driver as of now. Is there any harm in getting this error for additional drivers?

Comment: There is no harm. You can forget about it.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. :)